# Expire Content when Date has arrived Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to expire the content when a given date has been reached. If the date has not been reached, I would like the content not to have expired.

So currently, in my css, I have both `demo` and `demo1` set to `display:block;`

Then I do the following:

```
<p id="demo">hi</p>
<p id="demo1">hi2</p>

<script>
    var exp1 = "02/13/2018";
    var exp2 = "02/15/2018";
    var d = new Date();
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var now = curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year;

    if(now == exp1)
        document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
    else{
        if(now == exp2)
            document.getElementById("demo1").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
```

However, when I run the code, both paragraphs display their content rather then only the `<p>` tag that has `hi2` that should only appear. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: This checks only if it's *the* day, not after nor before. Also, you shouldn't do this client-side. Someone can change their machine's date, or edit your source on the client.

Comment: When debugging your now variable is equal to "2/13/2018" Notice that the month is only 1 digit where you are comparing a zero-leading month  of "02". It doesn't work because "2/13/2018" does not equal "02/13/2018"

Comment: @Li357 You are correct. In this case, I am aware when the expiration dates will be for the content and thus it is set if its is the day. And you are correct that someone can change their machines date or edit source on the client

Comment: @daddygames: Thank You. I didnt even see that. Urghh. Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding leading zero to your month and day value when its value is less than 10. You can add leading zeroes to number less than 10 by checking if month and day value is less than 10 and adding leading zeroes.

```js
var exp1 = "02/13/2018";
var exp2 = "02/15/2018";
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
if(curr_date < 10)
  curr_date = '0' + curr_date;
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
if(curr_month < 10)
  curr_month = '0' + curr_month;
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var now = curr_month + "/" + curr_date + "/" + curr_year;
if(now == exp1)
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
else{
    if(now == exp2)
        document.getElementById("demo1").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">hi</p>
<p id="demo1">hi2</p>
```

You can also use `date#toISOString` and `string#replace` to generate the date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format.

```js
var exp1 = "02/13/2018";
var exp2 = "02/15/2018";
var date = new Date();
now = date.toISOString().substring(0,10).replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/,'$2/$3/$1')
if(now == exp1)
    document.getElementById("demo").style.display = "none";
else{
    if(now == exp2)
        document.getElementById("demo1").style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">hi</p>
<p id="demo1">hi2</p>
```